# How to override Magento _formatPrice function to only show prices including tax for options

Tags: magento, overriding

In a Magento shop I want to show prices including and excluding tax. So I have configured the prices to show like this. But for product options, I want prices only to show including tax.

The prices excluding tax can't be selected with a CSS selector, so can't be hidden with CSS.

The option price html is generated by the protected `_formatPrice` function of the abstract `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract` class.

I want to override this function with my own. I have created a module `Company/ProdOptionsOnlyIncluding`.

This module contains one class located in `app/local/Company/ProdOptionsOnlyIncluding/Block/Abstract.php`:

```
class Company_ProdOptionsOnlyIncluding_Block_Abstract extends
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract{
    protected function _formatPrice($value, $flag=true)
    {
         // code
    }    
}
```

The module contains a `config.xml` to make sure the new class is used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_options_abstract>Company_ProdOptionsOnlyIncluding_Block_Abstract</product_view_options_abstract>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

The module is enabled, but the function is not overridden, because the output doesn't change. I think `config.xml` is not correct. How can I override this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your class is `Company_ProdOptionsOnlyIncluding_Block_Abstract` yet in the file you have called it `Company_ProdOptionsOnlyIncluding_Abstract`. It is missing a "Block".